# What is the difference between MULE Studio and MULE ESB?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-module-jpa

I am new in mule soft. i dont know what is the difference between mule studio and mule esb. both software are looking same only. mule studio is graphical representation as well as we can generate by code also. how can i differentiate both. what is the use of mule esb. where we can use the mule esb. how we can use this mule esb. i need exact difference between mule esb and mule studio. which  one is best for integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mule Studio is a graphical tool for creating integration applications that can be deployed to Mule ESB. You can also create Mule applications without the Studio, but usually you develop them in the Studio, and then run in the ESB standalone. You can not use Studio to run applications in production, it is just a development tool.

Comment: Thanks! to your valuable answer

Comment: can you give any Real time example

Comment: I don't quite get what you are looking for. You could use Mule Studio to create an application that periodically retrieves data from Twitter and publishes it Facebook. Or create a web form that immediately sends the input data to your email. When you are done, you package your application and run it in Mule ESB installed in your production server.

Answer (score 1):

Mule Studio is the design time. It's an IDE.

MuleESB is the run time.

MuleStudio is also known as AnyPoint Studio and is used to design a 'flow', which is basically an integration having endpoints (inbound and outbound) and some pressing in-between. The Studio allows a visual or graphical view to design this flow. It supports round-tripping between the graphical and XML views. The Studio comes with an embedded runtime of the MuleESB.

The MuleESB is where the 'flow' designed in the Studio gets deployed. It is akin to an application server in concept. There are two versions available - a free, forum supported community edition and a paid for, SLA defined enterprise edition. The enterprise edition is a super set of the community edition in terms of features and capability.

Answer (score 0):

mule studio is development id to design the mule flows,where as mule esb is runtime

Answer (score 0):

Mule Studio is just kind of Graphical IDE.

Answer (score 0):

MuleStudio is an eclipse based IDE to develope applications and all.Its a graphical design tool.
Where as MuleEsb is a Runtime environment to deploy the applications

Answer (score 0):

Now Mule has moved to anypoint studio. They have launch a new look with lots of good features. Anypoint studio is the development environment for any service which you are developing or mule esb

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything to differentiate b/w mule studio and mule esb. Both are part of mule product. Studio will help you in developing flows which can be deployed mule runtime (ESB).